# consecutive increasing subsequence

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm am trying to look for the longest increasing consecutive sub-sequence in a list.

example: if I have a list: `[1,2,3,0,2,3,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,9]` the output should be `[0,2,3,5,6,7]` as it's longer than `[1,2,3]` and `[1,4,5,6,9]`

I have written my code where I can break my list into smaller lists (as shown above) but only calculate the length of each smaller sequence. But what I need to do is output the longest sub-sequence and not its length, for some weird reason I just cannot seem to be able to do that (I keep getting logical errors).

So here's my code and this is one way I tried to implement it, the problem I am facing is when appending `temp` to `arr2`. Please help me fix this and do suggest an alternative and more efficient algorithm I could use for this?

```
arr = [1,2,3,0,2,3,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,9] #original list 
arr2 = [] #empty list (2 dimension)
counter  = 1 

temp = [] #temporary list
for x,y in enumerate(arr):

    if(x == 0):
        temp.append(y) #append first value to temp
    else:

        if(arr[x] > arr[x-1]): #if value of x is greater than previous one:

            counter += 1 #increase counter if condition met
            temp.append(y) #append list value to temp

        else: #if value of x is not greater than previous one:

            print(temp)
            arr2.append(temp) #append entire temp list to arr2
            temp[:] = [] #clear the temp list
            temp.append(y) #append the new lowest value to temp
            counter = 1 #reset counter

print(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are copying a reference to the list when you write:
`arr2.append(temp)`
And you then update the list `temp`, so you end up with several references to the same list in `arr2`.
You should make a copy of the list instead:
`arr2.append(temp[:])`

Also, you never copy the last subsequence found so you are missing one in `arr2`.
You can do it outside of the `for` loop for example:

```
        else: #if value of x is not greater than previous one:

            print(temp)
            arr2.append(temp) #append entire temp list to arr2
            temp[:] = [] #clear the temp list
            temp.append(y) #append the new lowest value to temp
            counter = 1 #reset counter

arr2.append(temp[:])
print(arr2)
```

With the above, you will get `[[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 4, 5, 6, 9]]` when you print `arr2`.
Then, it is only a matter of selecting the longest list inside.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. But just a quick correction, yes I do need the last subsequence to be appended to arr2 outside the loop, but I will also need to make a copy of the list inside the last else statement, should be arr2.append(temp[:]).. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First let `l0` be the given list:

```
l0 = [1,2,3,0,2,3,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,9]
```

Next we create a list of all the contiguous sublists of `l0`, but we throw out the ones that aren't increasing (see the `if` statement ending the generator object).

```
l1 = [l0[i:j] for i in xrange(len(l0)-1) for j in xrange(i,len(l0)) if l0[i:j] == sorted(l0[i:j])] ## all substrings of l0 that are increasing.
```

What you asked for is the longest such substring. So just return the max of the lengths of those:

```
print max([len(l) for l in l1])
```

Comment: shouldn't the l's in your list comprehension be l0 ? l is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This is the most efficient algorithm for the above problem. It has a time complexity of `O(N)` and a space complexity of `O(1)`.

- Iterate from the beginning of the array.
- Check if the next element is greater than the current element. If yes, then increment the end position of the array. Then check if this length is better than the all time maximum length encountered till now. If yes, then initialize the `beststart` and `bestend` with the current start and end respectively.
- If the next element is not greater than the current element, then re-initialize the start and end positions.

Here is a simple implementation of the above algorithm:

```
arr = [1,2,3,0,2,3,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,9] #original list 

l = len(arr)  # l stores the length of the array
i = 0  # initialize i, iterate from left of the array

max = 1  # the max is always a one element array

start = 0  # initialize start at the beginning of the array
end = 0  # initialize end at the beginning of the array

beststart = 0  # initialize beststart at the beginning of the array
bestend = 0  # initialize bestend at the beginning of the array

while i<l:
    if i+1 < l and arr[i+1]>arr[i]:
        end = end + 1  # increment end, as we found a longer array
        if (end-start+1) > max:
            max = (end - start + 1)  # update max
            beststart = start  # update beststart as we have the longest array till this point
            bestend = end  # update bestend as we have the longest array till this point
    else:
        start = i+1  # re-initialize start
        end = i+1  # re-initialize end

    i = i + 1

print (arr[beststart:bestend+1])  # print the longest array
```

**Output**: `[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 0):

A solution without creating a new list.

```
def max_inc_seq(seq):
    first_ret = first_curr = 0
    last_ret = last_curr = 0
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        if seq[i] > seq[i-1]:
            last_curr = i  # move pointer to the item
        else:
            last_curr = first_curr = i  # reset pointers
        len_curr = last_curr - first_curr 
        len_ret = last_ret - first_ret
        if len_curr > len_ret:  # the current seq. longer what longest for now
            first_ret = first_curr
            last_ret = last_curr            
    return seq[first_ret:last_ret+1]
```

Tests for `max_inc_seq`:

```
seqs = (
    ([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]),
    ([1,2,3,0,2,3,5,6,7,1,4,5,6,9], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]),
    ([1, 0], [1]),
    ([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]),
    ([0, 1, 1], [0, 1]),
    )

for seq, test in seqs:
    ret = max_inc_seq(seq)
    assert ret == test, "{} != {}".format(ret, test)
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) solution with 2 pointers technique:

```
def longest_inc_seq(arr):
    s, f = 0, 0
    S, F = 0, 0
    currentMaxLen = 0
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        f += 1
        # if the next element is smaller, reset the slow pointer
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
            s = i + 1
        # update currentMaxLen, S and F if the distance between the pointers 
        # is bigger than the currentMaxLen from the last iteration
        if (f-s) > currentMaxLen:
            S, F = s, f
            currentMaxLen = f-s
    print arr[S:F+1]
```